# What date/time format is this? COBOL Output

Tags: formatting, cobol, date-formatting

I seem to have an issue figuring out what date format a program in COBOL is storing data in.

```
DATE_SCHD
A80911
A80911
B00324
A51021
A51028
A60518
B50204
B50204
B50204
B50204
B50206
B50202
B50206
B50210
```

Any clues?

Comment: Can you post any data-definitions and code which uses those definitions? What type of system is it? Can it have future dates? Dates that are many years old?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is code that predates Y2K, then it is likely that it was storing in YYMMDD format and rather than being expanded from 6 to 8 bytes it was adapted to express the YY as a hex-like extension of 20th century two digit years.  That still leaves two possibilities though. If both digits are interpreted as hex, then A5 = 2005, A6 = 2006, A8 = 2008, B5 = 2021, etc. But if only the first digit is interpreted as hex, then B5 = 2015.

You'll need to examine the code that manipulates these dates, or at least try feeding it some new test data, in order to figure it out for sure.

Comment: The lack of A-F in the second character argues strongly against two-character hex. No one-line to convert to/from hex in COBOL, either. If it is a single character, without knowing what the base decade (or year) is, then guessing the value would have little value.

Comment: It's been a long time since my COBOL days so I don't remember much, but I'm not surprised at all that there's no one-line conversion to/from hex.

Comment: So makes it less likely. All those February dates at the end *do* make it look like B5 is 2015. 200=A, 201=B, 202=C etc looks possible, if dumb.

Comment: Richard, thanks for the response. This was exactly it after a lengthy confirmation process; only the first digit was interpreted as hex.